# Gridview EditItemTemplate with an If statement inside bind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, if-statement, bind

I tried a ton of solutions for problem: binding a textbox if the value is a number or null if it's anything else...

i have this textbox inside an EditItemTemplate

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Position") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

i tried to assign rangevalidators, regex validation but nothing works: it keeps erroring out when i try a non-number (like 'p' or 'word')

What i try to do is something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# if (It is number) Bind("Position") else Bind("Null") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

or something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# if (It is number) Bind("Position") else Bind("0") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Thanks everyone

PS: im using C#

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `Eval` instead of `Bind`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Int32.TryParse((string)Eval("Position"), out _foo) ? Eval("Position") : "0" %>' />
```

Of course you'll need the following declaration in the page:

```
private int _foo;
```